# Proving $\frac14(a+b+c+d)\geq \sqrt[4]{abcd}$

Tags: inequality

Can somebody help me how to prove that:

$$\frac14(a+b+c+d)\geq \sqrt[4]{abcd}$$

I'm sure it's easy, but I just can't figure out how! I've tried many ways.

Comment: You should show some of the many ways you've tried. This helps answerers tailor their responses to your experience and address your points of confusion, while avoiding telling you things you already know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: it is the AM-GM inequality for $n=4$: $$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\geq 0$$
$$\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{4}\geq \sqrt[4]{x_1x_2x_3x_4}$$
If we have proved the case $n=2$ we can prove this:
$$\frac{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}}{2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}}\geq \sqrt{\sqrt{x_1x_2}\sqrt{x_3x_4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

This gives ;

$$\frac{a+b+c+d}4\ge\sqrt[4]{abcd}$$

$$\implies a+b+c+d \ge 4\sqrt[4]{abcd}$$

NOTE: As Dr. Sonnhard Graubner pointed out the for cases of $n\ge 3$ the inequality needs to be proved.

As pointed out in his answer , when the case of $n = 2$ is proved;

one can prove ;

$$\frac{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}}{2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}}\geq \sqrt{\sqrt{x_1x_2}\sqrt{x_3x_4}}$$

Comment: But it is not a proof for $n=4$!

Comment: Oh sorry ,will edit my answer to include the proof. Thank you.